# How do I create a backup for a table which will be used for a full-refresh?

Tags: dbt

I have an incremental model A where each day is calculated using the previous day's value. Running a full-refresh means that this table needs to be calculated since the beginning of time which is very inefficient and takes too long.

I have tried to create a backup table which will take a copy of the table's value each month, and have model A refer to the backup table during a full-refresh so that the values only after the backup need to be recalculated and I can arrive at today's value much quicker. However this gives me an error:

```
Encountered an error:
Found a cycle: model.model_A --> model.backup --> model.model_A
```

This is because the backup refers to the model to get the value each month, while model A also refers to the backup to build off in the case of a full-refresh.

Is there a way around this problem, avoiding rebuilding the entire model from the beginning of time every time I do a full-refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't have 'circular loops' or cycles in your build process.

If there is an application that calculates the values for each day, you could perhaps store the new values back in the same source table(s), just adding a 'updated_at' or something similar. If I understand your use case correctly, you could then use this value whenever you need to query only the last day's information.